# Como puedo enviar archivos de un html a javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Bueno Tengo un codigo en c++ pero quiero pasarlo a html y javascript lo que quiero hacer es que con tres inputs que va a haber en la pagina ingresar numeros y que se pasen a javascript y alli hacer operaciones matematicas y que me devuelva un resultado en la pagina.

```js
var a = document.getElementById("inA");
var b = document.getElementById("inB");
var c = document.getElementById("inC");

var discriminante;
var raiz;
var resultado;
var cuatro;
var raiz1;
var dividir;

raiz1 = b * b - cuatro * a * c;
discriminante = b * b - 4 * a * c;
raiz = b * b - 4 * a * c;
raiz = Math.sqrt(raiz);
resultado = -1 * b;
dividir = 2 * a;
document.write(b * b);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Prueba</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="inA" type="text">
  <input id="inB" type="text">
  <input id="inC" type="text">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Disculpa, podrías redactar mejor tu pregunta?, de mi parte no entiendo exactamente lo que pides.

Comment: Buenas, me uno a la petición de @BDOM intenta formular mejor la pregunta, saludos!

Comment: Tengo entendido que tu lo que quieres es poder hacer operaciones matemáticas en una página web. Pues bien, lo que tienes que hacer es recoger el valor del input con la propiedad value y luego pasarlo por la operación matemámtica, y que acto seguido sea mostrado en pantalla. Es eso lo que deseas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo lo que querés hacer agregando un `eventListener` cuando se hace un cambio en el `input` y mostrando el resultado. Lo único que deberías hacer es reemplazar la ecuación que quieras mostrar.

```js
// asigno los elementos a una variable
var elementA = document.getElementById("inA");
var elementB = document.getElementById("inB");
var elementC = document.getElementById("inC");
var pre = document.getElementById("pre");

// agrego los listener en el on change para que
// realice las ecuaciones en los input
elementA.addEventListener('change', recalcular);
elementB.addEventListener('change', recalcular);
elementC.addEventListener('change', recalcular);

function recalcular() {
  // asigno el valor del input y si está vacío
  // le asigno por defaul el valor 0
  var a = parseFloat(elementA.value || 0);
  var b = parseFloat(elementB.value || 0);
  var c = parseFloat(elementC.value || 0);
  
  var discriminante;
  var raiz;
  var resultado;
  var cuatro;
  var raiz1;
  var dividir;

  // ecuaciones
  raiz1 = b * b - 4 * a * c;
  discriminante = b * b - 4 * a * c;
  raiz = b * b - 4 * a * c;
  raiz = Math.sqrt(raiz);
  resultado = -1 * b;
  dividir = 2 * a;
  
  // muestro en el tag "pre" el valor de la ecuación
  pre.innerText = b * b;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Prueba</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="inA" type="text">
  <input id="inB" type="text">
  <input id="inC" type="text">
  <div>
    <label>Resultado:</label>
    <pre id="pre"></pre>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```